# Behavior of coil and resistance in DC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, induction

I have a simple circuit of a coil parallel to a resistance and then in series with another resistance. I wanted to understand the behavior of this circuit so I ran a simulation, and what I noticed is that the current $I_1$ through $R_1$ is changing like the voltage $U_1$. I also noticed that $U_1+U_2=U_0$, that is logical, because we can't make voltage from nothing... What I am interested is, why does the current and voltage change and how can I calculate them? [image: Circuit]

$R_1=1.2\,\Omega, R_2=806.7\,\Omega,L=400H,U_0=240V$

Comment: what are U1 and U2. I think when you switch on the circuit the current increases and you will have inductive load which results in slower increase in current and same is true when current is decreased the coil will cause slow decrease in current.

Comment: $U_1$ is the voltage on the resistor $R_1$ and $U_2$ is the voltage on $R_2$ and $L$

Comment: What voltage have you measured in $U_2$? I suppose it is small..

Comment: I think it is because $U_1 = I_1R_1$, with $R_1$ constant, $U_1$ is proportional to $I_1$

Comment: Have you looked up coil (inductor) in your textbook or on the internet?

Comment: @philip_0008 At the start $U_2=U_0$ and with time it gets lower.

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes, I have. But I am more used to use coils (inductors) in AC circuits. When it gets to DC I get a bit confused... The current is always increasing, probably exponentialy ($1-e^{-x}$), but I can't find the maximum or sth similar.

Comment: This question has some merit in that the transient behaviour when the switch is closed there must be an initial current of zero through resistor R2 and inductor L so terms like voltage should perhaps not be used without careful qualification.  I do not think that this question should be closed as this is what the problem is all about?

Answer (score 1):

The inductor works the same as it does in AC circuits : the PD across it is related to the current through it by $V = L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

You are correct : the current I through L increases in proportion to $1-e^{-kt}$ towards a maximum value.  Meanwhile $\frac{dI}{dt}$ decreases from a maximum value to zero.  When the maximum current flows it is constant, and there is no longer any impedance from L because then $\frac{dI}{dt}=0$.  L then acts as a short circuit across $R_2$.

http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee201/topics/capacitors_inductors/RL_transients.pdf